# Windows 10 Swapfile/pagefile on D: drive not being used

Tags: windows-10, memory, pagefile, swap-file

I am having issues mainly with backup software like DPM, where swapfiles cannot be excluded, and the recommendation seems to be to put the swapfile on a second disk/partition that is not being backed-up. So far so.. well.. but now:

**The Swapfile on drive D: is not being used.**

I managed to get the Swapfile on drive C: down to ~20MB after disabling the crash dump, setting D: to 100-32000MB. Without swapfile, the system quickly becomes unusable with 16GB of RAM..

[image: Windows Swapfile config 1]

[image: Windows Swapfile config 2]

Of course I rebooted several times.

(I also tried "size maintained by system" on D: drive, didn't work any better.)

How can I make such a configuration work successfully?

Comment: Update: it seems like Windows "forgets" the swap file on the D: drive after a restart. Showing system files, I can see it is missing. After setting it again several times in the settings, changing the size, getting (and ignoring) restart messages, the file pagefile.sys appears on the D: drive, and the worries are gone till the next reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on several systems now. All Hyper-V VM guests, all Windows 10.

It disappeared on first system, on 2nd I coulnd't make it work - so I created a Windows task that is executed on Login. Could have been startup but I figured login is a little later and less critical in that all services should be started.

```
# parse output of command for number of mentions of pagefile on d: drive
$count = (wmic pagefile list /format:list | out-string -stream | select-string d:\\pagefile).length
# if no pagefile on d, create it (still works without check - it would just fail if file already in use)
if ($count -eq 0)
{
    # with above thest, this code should never execute
    $pagefileset = Gwmi win32_pagefilesetting | where{$_.caption -like 'D:*'}
    $pagefileset.Delete()
    # create pagefile with desired size - should alway work, since only decreasing size results in needed reboot
    Set-WMIInstance -class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="d:\pagefile.sys";InitialSize = 800;MaximumSize =20000}
    Write-Host res-set pagefile on D:
} else {
    Write-Host pagefile already existed on d: drive
}
```

this can be executed as

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File c:\tools\recreate_swapfile.ps1
```

If you execute on login on a shared PC, make sure it executes for each user and as admin (passwords doesn't need to be saved).

You can check success with

```
wmic pagefile list /format:list
```

which should list file on C: (hard to get rid of, but can be small like 100MB) and the desired swapfile on top.